# Jade doesn't compile to Html when using i18next in Express (and Grunt)

Tags: node.js, express, pug, gruntjs, i18next

I'm trying to compile jade templates to html but my terminal send me an error. (I'm using grunt and the npm `grunt-contrib-jade`).

In my jade file I have

> span= .t("article.mainboxCategory")

I taped `grunt jade` and my terminal returns me

> Cannot call method 't' of undefined

I read [the documentation](http://i18next.com/node/pages/doc_templates.html), but I'm not sure to understand what I can and need to put in my Grundfile or in my app.js (wich load Express and i18next).

Someone can help ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the point. Then it should work fine, imo.

```
span= t("article.mainboxCategory")
```

Currently you are trying to call the method 't' from the object ''. Which is obviously not defined since it's nothing.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to remove the dot, but I always have an error
`undefined is not a function`

Comment: I am also getting this. Yet I don't have a dot.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add the line `app.use(i18n.handle);`. Works now.